NLog IgnoreFinal and LogFinal - are ALL subsequent rules ignored ? or only those matching the current filter rule?
The NLogs docs (https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/When-filter#parameters) say:
IgnoreFinal - The message should not be logged and ignore any following logging-rules.
LogFinal - The message should be logged and ignore any following logging-rules.
The question is:
What is exactly is meant by : "...ignore any following logging-rules."
Does IgnoreFinal block all subsequent rules that have the exact same rule conditions as the current rule (the one with 'ignoreFinal') ?
As I understand:
Each "filter-rule" has 3 "things" that the "log-entry" must match:

min-level
max-level
the condition (e.g. length('${message}') > 100 or any other variation...)

So - for example - if you have:
Filter 1: min=Debug max=Fatal condition=length('${message}') > 100 action=IgnoreFinal
Filter 2: min=Trace max=Warn condition=length('${message}') > 100 action=Log

Will all log-entries that match "Filter 2" be ignored ? 
or - 
log-entries with "Trace" will get logged ?
because Trace is Not part of the rule in "Filter 1"

NLog will use the filter-result of the first matching filter. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/359752c394bdf35ee653852f3803b581f4cc18ac/src/NLog/LoggerImpl.cs#L173

It is possible to have multiple logging-rules defined. Where the NLog LogEventInfo is matched against all the logging-rules from top to bottom, and for each logging-rule that matches the logger-name-pattern and loglevel, then the NLog LogEventInfo is redirected to the configured targets. When using final="true" or action="IgnoreFinal" then it will stop matching against any the following logging-rules (early exit). See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Filtering-log-messages
